# How do I optimize my hive query for finding Sum of Count of Records from multiple tables

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hiveql, qubole

I’ve to generate a report that will give me the **sum of the counts** from tables A, B and C for events that have been stored using Hive and my S3 buckets have been partitioned by Organization_id

For eg:
Table A – Has a record for every day John (and other employees) goes to work
Table B – Has a record for every call that John (and other employees) makes or takes at work
Table C – Has a record for every expense that John(and other employees)  submits at work

Basically I want a sum of the counts from A, B and C for John (employee_id) in the last month. There should be **only one record for every date** if there is a record in any of the 3 tables A, B or C (and sum the counts if there is a record for a date in one or more of the tables). So my Output is:

```
Employee id
Employee Name 
Date
Count
123
John
02-Jan-2016
55
123
John
12-Jan-2016
88
123
John
19-Jan-2016
103
```

The query that I came up with is:

```
select  adcts.employee_name, adcts.employee_id,Total_count as event_count, adcts.event_date  
from   
       (select   coalesce(Evts.employee_id,imps.employee_id,AEvts.employee_id) as   employee_id  
        ,   coalesce(Evts.employee_name,imps.employee_name,AEvts.employee_name) as   employee_name  
        , coalesce(Evts.Event_count,0) + coalesce(Imps.Impression_count,0)   + coalesce (AEvts.Event_Count,0)as Total_Count  
        , coalesce (Evts.event_date,imps.impression_date, AEvts.event_date)   as event_date  
    from  
        (select employee_id, employee_name, count(*) as   Event_count,event_date  
         from mm_events  
         where organization_id = 100048  
         and event_date between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-04'  
        group by employee_id, employee_name,event_date) Evts  
       full outer join  
        (select employee_id, employee_name, count(*) as Impression_count,   impression_date   
         from mm_impressions  
         where organization_id = 100048  
         and impression_date between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-04'  
        group by employee_id, employee_name,impression_date) Imps  
        on Evts.employee_id = Imps.employee_id  
       full outer join  
        (select employee_id, employee_name, count(*) as   Event_count,event_date  
         from mm_attributed_events  
         where organization_id = 100048  
         and event_date between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-04'  
         and event_type = 'click'  
        group by employee_id, employee_name,event_date) AEvts  
     on AEvts.employee_id=Evts.employee_id  
       ) adcts     
join  
        (select distinct c.employee_id from default.t1_meta_dmp c   
         where c.employee_dmp_enabled='inherits'  
         and c.agency_dmp_enabled = 'inherits'  
         and c.agency_status='true'  
         and c.employee_status='true'  
         and c.organization_id = 100048) cc  
on adcts.employee_id=cc.employee_id  
order by adcts.employee_id asc
```

I have 2 questions:

**1.    Do I have the right query?
2. Because I’m using ‘full outer join’ I get more than one entry for the same date. Can someone suggest a better way to achieve the result? Different query maybe**

Answer (score 0):

You are getting more than one entry for the same `date` because you are grouping by `date` in subqueries but joining them only by `employee_id`. That is why your records are duplicated after join. You should add `event_date` to the join condition as well.

It seems you do not need `FULL JOIN` at all. Join is more expensive than `union all`. Use UNION ALL select from each table then `group by employee_name, employee_id, event_date` and aggregate count() :

```
select employee_id, employee_name, sum(Event_count) as Total_Count , event_date 
    from
    (
    select employee_id, employee_name, count(*) as Event_count, event_date  from mm_events 
    where organization_id = 100048 and event_date between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-04'
group by employee_id, employee_name, event_date

    union all  
    select employee_id, employee_name, count(*) as Event_count, impression_date as event_date   
    from mm_impressions
     where organization_id = 100048 and impression_date between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-04' 
group by employee_id, employee_name,impression_date

    union all 
    select employee_id, employee_name, count(*) as Event_count,event_date  
    from mm_attributed_events 
    where organization_id = 100048  and event_date between '2016-02-01' and '2016-02-04'  and event_type = 'click'
group by employee_id, employee_name, event_date
    ) adcts
    group by employee_id, employee_name, event_date
```

Add your join with cc query to the above query.

All subqueries in UNION ALL will run in parallel